# Exception for missing r:layoutResources tag

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am using `grails 2.3.4`

However when I start my application I get:

```
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/testApplication
....[/testApplication].[gsp] Servlet.service() for servlet [gsp] in context w
ith path [/testApplication] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:la
youtResources tag. After rendering your page the following have not been rendere
d: [defer]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewIns
tance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:986)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstru
ctor.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteN
oUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstru
ctor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor
(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor
(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
        at org.grails.plugin.resource.DevModeSanityFilter.doFilter(DevModeSanity
Filter.groovy:54)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doF
ilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilte
rInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterIntern
al(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(D
elegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(Delegat
ingFilterProxy.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoin
t.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My `index.gsp` file looks like that:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
<title>Title Page</title>

<!-- here we are loading angularjs -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- other way: <script src="" $ {resource(dir: 'js/lib', file: 'file.js')}"></script>  -->
<!-- <r:require module="angular" />
<r:layoutResources />
 -->
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
          <hr>
          <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the tag is commented out. So why do I get this and how to fix this long expeception?

I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<r:layoutResources/>` should appear *twice* in your page (or more usually in your layout GSP) - once just before `</head>` to render resources with the "head" disposition and again just before `</body>` to render the "defer" ones.  It's the missing second occurrence that the error message is complaining about, the first isn't really "commented out" (it's inside an HTML comment so it will still be rendered, but its output will be commented out in the resulting HTML).

So you need to "uncomment" the first occurrence and also add the second one, or make sure that your page is using a layout that includes the `<r:layoutResources/>` tags at the right places.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! Is there a real difference if I use `   <r:layoutResources disposition="defer"/>`?

Comment: @user2051347 you don't need to - by default the first occurrence of the tag will do the "head" resources and the second will do the "defer" ones.